# Mac OS X apps Instagram api

Tags: objective-c, macos, instagram, instagram-api

I am developing an application for Mac OS X app would have to communicate with Instagram for accessing data.

I have searched alot but found no api for Mac OS X from Instagram Site can anyone guide me is there any api that i can use to accomplish what I want.

I know there is iOS help available but nothing for Mac OS X.

Comment: Please describe the issue in detail. What is not working? There is an API from Instagram, why should there be a specific one for Max OS X?

Comment: Check my answer below it would be done via GTM OAuth2.0 and I have provided you some sample code for others as well.procedure would be similar.

Answer (score 0):

I am going through same issues for a Mac OS X application.I found links over here.

https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/source/browse/trunk/Examples/OAuthSample/OAuthSampleAppController.m?r=39

You would have to use GTM OAuth2.0.as explained at the above link.Method would be similar as above but its for other services you would have to custom design it for Instagram.